# Spark's example throws FileNotFoundException in client mode

Tags: apache-spark, ubuntu, hadoop, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I have: Ubuntu 14.04, Hadoop 2.7.7, Spark 2.2.0.

I just installed everything.

When I try to run the the Spark's example:

```
bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode client \
               --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
               examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.2.0.jar 10
```

I get the following error:

> INFO yarn.Client:
>            client token: N/A
>            diagnostics: Application application_1552490646290_0007 failed 2 times due to AM Container for
>   appattempt_1552490646290_0007_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000 For
>   more detailed output, check application tracking
>   page:http://ip-123-45-67-89:8088/cluster/app/application_1552490646290_0007 Then,
>   click on links to logs of each attempt. Diagnostics: File
>   file:/tmp/spark-f5879f52-6777-481a-8ecf-bbb55e376901/__spark_libs__6948713644593068670.zip
>   does not exist java.io.FileNotFoundException: File
>   file:/tmp/spark-f5879f52-6777-481a-8ecf-bbb55e376901/__spark_libs__6948713644593068670.zip
>   does not exist

```
 at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.deprecatedGetFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:611)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileLinkStatusInternal(RawLocalFileSystem.java:824)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:428)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.copy(FSDownload.java:253)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.access$000(FSDownload.java:63)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:361)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload$2.run(FSDownload.java:359)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:421)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:358)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.FSDownload.call(FSDownload.java:62)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I get the same error both in client mode and cluster mode.

Comment: Do you try to run it with Yarn or standalone in local mode ?

Comment: @SimbaPK on YARN

Comment: did you check if the user executing spark has the correct rights in your tmp folder?

Comment: @DanielSobrado I just made the hadoop user owner of the /tmp folder, but I still get the same error

Comment: @DanielSobrado is that OK? drwxrwxrwt   8 hadoop hadoop  4096 Mar 19 09:17 tmp

Comment: @DanielSobrado "hadoop" is also my Spark user BTW

Comment: Can you check fs.defaultFS in core-site.xml at spark yarn configurations. When this parameter wasn't defined in the core-site.xml this error can be occur.

Comment: @slmn I don't have a core-site.xml in spark folder. I have a core-site.xml in hadoop folder, and the <configuration> node is empty.

Comment: What about yarn conf folder?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it fails by loading the spark libs. As Daniel points out, it could be related to your read rights. Besides, it could be related to running out of disk space.

However, in our case to avoid transfer latencies to the master and read/write rights in the local machine, we put the **spark-libs** in the HDFS of the Yarn cluster and then, we point them in the `spark.yarn.archive` property.

```
jar cv0f spark-libs.jar -C $SPARK_HOME/jars/ .
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hadoop
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /apps/spark/
hadoop fs -put -f  ${SPARK_HOME}/spark-libs.jar /apps/spark/
```

```
# spark-defaults.conf
spark.yarn.archive hdfs:///apps/spark/spark-libs.jar
```

Comment: I was executing this from the EMR master. From where are you trying to execute it?

Comment: Then, it could be your hadoop configuration. Check your hdfs-site.xml the dfs.namenode properties, to verify that they have the EMR master ip.

Comment: I don't work with EMR. I am trying to use a simple Hadoop standalone with Spark for training purpose.

Comment: Then, if it's standalone try to point to a local path. (i.e spark.yarn.archive file:///tmp/spark-libs.jar)

Answer (score 0):

First, Path to a bundled jar including your application and all dependencies. The URL must be globally visible inside of your cluster, for instance, an hdfs:// path or a file:// path that is present on all nodes.

Second , If you run on YARN mode you have point your master to yarn [submitting-applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html), and put your jar file in hdfs

```
# Run on a YARN cluster
# Connect to a YARN cluster in client or cluster mode depending on the value 
# of --deploy-mode. The cluster location will be found based on the HADOOP_CONF_DIR 
# or YARN_CONF_DIR variable. 

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=XXX
./bin/spark-submit \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \  # can be client for client mode
hdfs://path/to/spark-examples.jar
1000
```